# Allocations Generation keeps growing

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I ran the Allocations Instrument for my app to check the memory growth as the app was crashing because of low memory after running for a few days. It's an app running on Guided Access mode which is on 24/7.

The project is using ARC and I've checked for retain cycles even though I'm not sure if there are still some.

This generation data recorded is for showing only one overlay view and then closing it repeatedly.

I've been trying to solve this for quite some time. What could be causing so much growth? Please help. Thanks!

Please look at the screenshot via this link as I do not have enough reputation to post images. [Allocations Instrument Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riv8A.png)